# Solutions which Disrupt Equilibrium of Ferric Chloride and Potassium Thiocyanate Reaction

Tags: equilibrium

Consider the reaction involving ferric chloride and potassium thiocyanate,

$$\ce{Fe^{3+}(aq) + SCN-(aq) <=> FeSCN^{2+}(aq) }$$

,where $Cl^-(aq)$ and $K^+(aq)$ are spectators. Here's my thinking on what could happen if disruptions arise.

If $I^-(aq)$ is added a redox reaction decreases $Fe^{3+}(aq)$ concentration so the reverse reaction is favored.

If $Cl^-(aq)$ is added then it will react with ferric ions and cause the reverse reaction to be favored. My understanding is that this reaction is always taking place but the addition of more chlorine ions speeds it up.

The addition of $K^+(aq)$ to the solution would not cause any reaction as it is unreactive with the other substances present.

If $CO_3^-(aq)$ is added a precipitate with the ferric ions causes the reverse reaction to be favored.

If $Pb^{2+}(aq)$ is added nothing would happen since plumbous thiocyanate is soluble.

Is this logic sound? Why would chlorine actually disrupt equilibrium when added if it's already present as a spectator and is there a general non experimental way to determine if additional ions will disrupt equilibrium?

Comment: See CH SE META post about [policy for "Am I right?" questions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/policy-on-amirite-questions)

Comment: Can Pb^2+ form the complex with SCN- too, being a competitive reaction?

Comment: Actually, do not need to add anything to disrupt the reaction other than strong light, see "A practical FeCl3/HCl photocatalyst for versatile aliphatic C–H functionalization" at https://www.cell.com/chem-catalysis/pdf/S2667-1093(22)00165-8.pdf 
, that notes "Efficient and cheap photocatalyst generated from FeCl3 and hydrochloric acid".  The ferric chloride photocatalyst is somewhat unique in liberating primarily solvated electrons reducing, in your particular equilibrium,  ferric to ferrous. Solutions with strong colors are generally prone to photocatalytic reactions.

Comment: @Poutnik I have edited the question to steer it away from solely being an "Am I right?" question.